# References resources between groups when using the CLI

Tags: azure, azure-cli2

Using the Azure CLI (v2), how do you reference a resource in one resource group when creating a resource in a different group that uses this resource. Or more simply, how do your specify cross-resource group references when using the CLI?

Should I be using the resource ID in cases such as this?

Answer (score 1):

OK, it appears that using the full resource ID works when references resources across resource groups. Is there an easier way? For example "resource-group-name/resource" or something similar?

Comment: No. Today, resource id is the only way to identify a resource in different resource group.